# AWS Aurora for PostgreSQL strange vacuum cost parameters

Tags: postgresql, vacuum, aws-aurora

Today, I found out that in AWS Aurora for PostgreSQL 11 the default cluster parameter `vacuum_cost_page_miss = 0` whereas `vacuum_cost_page_hit = 1`.

I'd love to understand the logic behind pricing a page miss as cheaper than a page hit.

Comment: See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64548853/vacuum-cost-page-miss-set-to-zero)